# Is using a Repository Abstraction over Entity Framework Good Practice or not?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am about to begin on a new project, which will use Entity Framework(EF) as the ORM to link with SQL Server.  I have been doing a large amount of reading to understand what are good approaches to working with EF with regards to abstraction and ultimately making my code testable.

Problem is the more reading I do the more confused I become with it all.

**What I thought was a good way to go:**

I was going to go down the repository route, make them so they are easily injectable via interfaces and easy to mock for testing purposes, from a lot of the examples i seem to find, there are many who swear by this approach.  For the repository parts that interact with EF, I was just going to go with integration tests because there would be no business logic in my Repos, I would shift that up into the Service/Controller classes to deal with that.

**Some Say the Repository Pattern is an unwarranted abstraction**

http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

*There were other links but i did not want to flood this question with too many*

I kind of get this, I understand that EF and the implementation of it is essentially an abstraction, but to me it seems like a concrete one (it hits something outside the scope of the application...the DB) The issue for me is it pushes the testing issue up for me (in the initial architecture at least) where I will probably interact with the Data Context and Unit of Work stuff from within my Service, but that feels like i am mixing data access login with business logic at that level and then how the hell do i unit test that?

I seem to have read so much that i now have no clear direction and inevitable coders block has set in.  I am trying to look for an approach that is clean and i can test against.

**UPDATE - Solution i am going to start off with**

I went a slightly different path then the one in the answer given by simon but thanks to an article that i had read but he submitted again so i went over it again.  Firstly i am using Code First as i have an existing database and for some reason don't like the designer tools.  I created some simple POCO objects and some mappings, to keep things simple here i am just going to show one POCO/Mapping and what not.

*POCO*

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
{
    [Key]
    public T Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}    

public class Project : BaseEntity<int>
{
    public virtual ICollection<Site> Sites { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

*Unit Of Work Interface*

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IDbSet<Project> Projects { get; }

    void Commit();
}
```

*Context*

```
internal class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectMap());
    }
}
```

*Concrete UnitOfWork*

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    readonly MyContext _context;
    const string ConnectionStringName = "DBConn";

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName].ConnectionString;
        _context = new FosilContext(connectionString);
    }

    public IDbSet<Project> Projects
    {
        get { return _context.Set<Project>(); }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

*Basic Test Code*

```
        var _repo = new UnitOfWork().Projects;
        var projects = from p in _repo
                       select p;

        foreach (var project in projects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3})", project.Id, project.Name, project.Active.ToString(), project.CreatedOn.ToShortDateString()));
        }

        Console.Read();
```

The UnitOfWork is self explanatory but based on a concrete context, i can create a fake IUnitOfWork and pass it in a fake IDBSet for testing.  For me, and this may come back to bite me architecturally the more i get into this but don't have a Repo on top of this abstracting EF away (I Think). As the Article explains IDbSet is an equivalent to a Repo so thats what i am using.  I am kinda hiding my custom context behind the UoW but i am going to see how that pans out.

What i am thinking now is i can use this in service layer, which will encapsulate the retrieval on data and business rules but should be unit testable as i can fake the EF specific items.  Hopefully that will make my controllers pretty lean, but we will see :)

Comment: Don't forget that if you are using Entity Framework, `DbContext` _is_ akin to a UnitOfWork and `DbSet` _is_ akin to a Repository. This question, I think, invites for personnal opinion and might not be suited for Stack Overflow but it is my opinion that if you are going to use Entity Framework, you might as well embrace the pattern. Further wrapping of the `DbContext` and the `DbSet`s is really to give a very thin abstraction over the concrete class for ease of unit testing and, to a certain extent, Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  What i am not getting (i am very new to EF) is what this thin layer would look like.  I was watching a video specifically about EF and testing and the author used IDBSet and introduced a IContext interface, but with a separate unit of work (these examples used a repository) which was passed in.  The thin layer was IDBSet and IContext but even the author noted you were hiding away EF with these abstractions which seemded exactly the same as the issue people have with the Repository Pattern?

Comment: I'm moving the wall of text back to my previous answer. The character limitations makes formatting a bit hard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't forget that if you are using Entity Framework, `DbContext` *is* akin to a UnitOfWork and `DbSet` *is* akin to a Repository. This question, I think, invites for personnal opinion and might not be suited for Stack Overflow but it is my opinion that if you are going to use Entity Framework, you might as well embrace the pattern. Further wrapping of the `DbContext` and the `DbSet`s is really to give a very thin abstraction over the concrete class for ease of unit testing and, to a certain extent, Dependency Injection.

There's a topic on MSDN ([Testability and Entity Framework 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff714955.aspx)) that can give you a good starting point. There are a few resources here and there of suggestion on how to implement this pattern in the context of Entity Framework. In most scenario, you will use a DbContext to perform `SaveChanges()` and the `DbSet<T>` to do your CRUD operations with the help of the `IQueryable<T>` implement on `DbSet<T>`. You can implement your IUnitOfWork to mimic what you need on your `DbContext` and same for `DbSet`.

An implementation in that regards would almost be a 1-to-1 mapping of the methods in `DbContext` and `DbSet<T>`, but you can also implement a custom IUnitOfWork that implements In-Memory based `IRepository<T>` (using `HashSet`s for example) that facilitate unit testing of the query logic against Queryable components. Is the repository pattern a good idea? This is what's debatable. It really depends on the projects and the flexibility you need and what you want your different layers to do (and what you don't want to).

**Edit to answer comment:**
Your `UnitOfWork` implementation should not inherit `DbContext` but create an instance, keep it private and delegate its own method call to the context. Your `Repository<T>` implementation would proably take a `DbSet<T>` in an internal constructor. One of the big advantage of the Model-First approach is the liberty given to assembly organization. What I usually end up doing is to separate the model and the DbContext in two separate assembly, the latter referencing the former. This scenario would look like:

1 - Your Models.dll assembly contains your POCO

2 -  Your Data.dll assembly contains your interfaces and implementation. You could also have (for example) Data.Core.dll that contains your interfaces and common utilities regarding your data access layer and have an interchangeable Data.Entity.dll (or Data.List.dll) for your actual implementation. If we go with the first option, it could look like:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork { /* Your methods */ }

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class { /* Your methods */ }

internal class YourDbContext : DbContext { /* Your implementation */ }

public class YourDatabaseContext : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly YourDbContext dbContext;

    public YourDatabaseContext()
    {
        // You could also go with the Lazy pattern here to defer creation
        dbContext = new YourDbContext();
    }
}

internal class DbSetRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> dbSet;

    public DbSetRepository(DbSet<T> dbSet)
    {
        // You could also use IDbSet<T> for a toned down version
        this.dbSet = dbSet;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, only your interface and your `IUnitOfWork` implementation is visible outside of the assembly (if you want to use Dependency Injection, for example). This is not crucial and is really a matter of design choices. Because your `DbContext` will be "linked" to your POCO by the definition of your internal implementation and everything will be wired up in your configurations.

Comment: Thanks for th link, I read that yesterday, but i think i was getting confused with naming as they use UoW instead of Context but it looks interchangeable here.  One thing (but this is not really related to this) is i could not find a place to add the mappings to link my model to the database which is why i tried to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Modika What do you mean by mappings ? Your EDMX ?

Comment: i am not using a EDMX as i was going down the code first approach, but the mappings connecting my POCOs to the database representation.  I have a bunch of EntityTypeConfiguration mappings, but i think, looking at that article, the concrete implementations of the context(UoF) could simply inherit from DbContext and then i have access to the OnModelCreating method... not sure if that would work though...

Comment: @Modika I started typing a comment and went way over the character limit. See my edit for the follow up.

Comment: Marked as answer, i am still unsure of implementing a repository as that was an abstraction i am reading is not needed, i may go and implement, it can always be changed later :) but as you said the repo here is a thinner abstraction and i can move domain/business specific functions up to the services like GetActiveOrders for instance keeping the repo layer thin

Answer (score 0):

We have been using our own ORM abstraction framework which supports repository, unit of work and specification patterns for a few years and based on our experience, I would definitely say Yes!

Such an abstraction does not necessarily guarantee interchangeability. Another very important benefit is extensibility.

For instance, for one project, after the release, a new requirement was a  "Published" property on some entities and the UI had to hide the entities which were unpublished. For this scenario, we extended our framework to support a "default specification" which is very similar to Hibernate's "session filters" which apply to all queries made over a single DbContext.

Since we already have a "request scoped" DbContext lifecycle system (which is actually the preferred way now in owin and .net core based apps) , it was very easy for us to add such a API:

```
CurrentContext.AddDefaultSpec( new Spec<Product>(t => t.Published) )
```

This call adds the given spec to the list of Product specs in current context and applies all Product specs to query expressions executed on

```
Repository<Product>.Query().Where(....)
```

Of course our spec system was already capable of merging expressions from multiple lambdas and specifications but it is out of scope here.

To execute this function we have developed a simple ASP .NET MVC filter attribute and in most of our controller actions ( except the administration parts ) we put this attribute.

One note: since abstracting both the sync and async methods was very hard and was not worth the effort,and also we need some EF specific calls like .Include() etc,  the client code still has references to the EF which does not help if we need to replace EF with another ORM. But this was not a requirement and in practise you don't come up with such a requirement in most projects.

So if the reason to abstract it with a repository is just to create a "ideal" platform independent API, and if you are not building a generic framework to target different ORMs or data access interfaces, I don't think it is the right way.

Our main purpose was to create a in-house framework based on EF with additional utilities, support for common design patterns and event driven customizeable unit of works ( i.e. observe events when some type of object is added to the uow ) so it was a suitable solution to the problem in hand. Though it was not very easy to implement.